# Removing duplicated factor levels

Tags: r

I am trying to order my ggplot by descending value but I continue receiving the error

```
Warning messages:
1: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

Even though I have used `unique()` in the formula

Here is an example of the data

```
   > melted
                                 Var1 variable      value
    150           Washington, DC - 17   norm.y 0.05253336
    147                 New York - 10   norm.y 0.03873103
    63                   Chicago - 17   norm.x 0.02417114
    37               New Orleans - 76   norm.x 0.02263347
    174                   Boston - 61   norm.y 0.02246400
    9                    Atlanta - 64   norm.x 0.02203998
```

I have tried

```
melted$Var1 <- factor(unique(melted$Var1, levels = melted$Var1[order(melted$value)]))
```

and

```
melted$Var1 <- factor(melted$Var1, levels = melted$Var1[order(unique(melted$value))])
```

but to no avail.  Any suggestions?

Basically, I have two sets of variables that I would like to plot by descending order of their `value`.  Names in `Var1` will therefore appear twice.

[image]

Comment: Your second try is almost there, but think about what you are trying to achieve. If you want unique levels everything passed to `levels` should be wrapped in `unique`. But if your `Var1` values are not unique, how is the sorting by `value` supposed to work? There could be two different `value`s for the same `Var1`.

Comment: In the first one you seem to have `unique()` that is applied to `melted$Var1` AND `levels=...`. Wouldn't it make more sense to have: `mmelted$Var1 <- factor(unique(melted$Var1), levels = unique(melted$Var1[order(melted$value)]))` ?

Comment: I think that both of your statements would give you unique values for Var1 but for the plot to work, the number of rows of the data should be equal to the number of elements being passed in the vector which will be fed in the order argument, which is where you are stuck.

Comment: All of the values of `Var1` are duplicated once because I am plotting two sets of variables. It is important that the values are plotted in descending order, but I am not sure how to organize this  - please see my edited question

Comment: forcats package helps with this sort of issue.